# How do I connect custom logging to my ef6 migrations?

Tags: c#, logging, entity-framework-6, serilog

I have a DbMigrationsConfiguration that looks like this:

```cs
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DatabaseProject.DB>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        }
    }
```

Elsewhere, in my DbContext class I have:

```cs
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DB, DbProject.Migrations.Configuration>(useSuppliedContext: true));
            // and so on...
```

And I want to use the MigrationsLogger to record some information when a migration is applied. So I set up a simple class like this using serilog:

```cs
    public class EfLogger : MigrationsLogger
    {
        public override void Info(string message)
        {
            Log.Logger.Information("Machine {name} reported EF Migration Message: {message}", Environment.MachineName,
                message);
        }

        public override void Warning(string message)
        {
            Log.Logger.Warning("Machine {name} reported EF Migration Warning: {message}", Environment.MachineName,
                message);
        }

        public override void Verbose(string message)
        {
            Log.Logger.Verbose("Machine {name} reported EF Migration verbose message: {message}", Environment.MachineName,
                message);
        }
    }
```

So how do I change my configuration to use the new logger? I can't find any examples or documentation on this anywhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you tagged your question with `Serilog`? From the looks of it, all you want to know is how to attach a custom `MigrationsLogger` implementation to Entity Framework, which is independent of the logging framework itself.

Comment: @julealgon I guess since I am using Serilog as a target and often there are specialized sinks for specific purposes, I thought maybe a Serilog guru might look at this and have a specific workaround.

Comment: See my answer for details on how to attach the logger. Seeing your log logic, I'd recommend looking into log enrichers. There is a native one that adds the machine name to all events (this eliminates the need for you to keep repeating on each log call).

Comment: Could you share precisely which version of EF6 you are using? Latest version of `DbMigrator` has 2 public constructors. https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/Migrations/DbMigrator.cs

Comment: @julealgon good point. We are using EF 6.2.0 and had balked at upgrading due to a bug with EF that was breaking applications deployed as Azure WebApps. I'll need to check that bug has been resolved before upgrading. But good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into how this works and I think you won't be able to use `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` directly. You should be able to override it though. If you look into the actual logic there it's actually quite simple:

https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion%60.cs

```
    public virtual void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        Check.NotNull(context, "context");

        var migrator = new DbMigrator(_config, _useSuppliedContext ? context : null);
        migrator.Update();
    }
```

To add your logging to it, create a new `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersionWithLogging` implementation that inherits from the standard `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`, then override the method and introduce a logging decorator before calling update. Something like this (untested):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.infrastructure.migratorloggingdecorator?view=entity-framework-6.2.0

```
    public override void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
    {
        _ = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        var migrator = new MigratorLoggingDecorator(
            new DbMigrator(_config, _useSuppliedContext ? context : null),
            new EfLogger());

        migrator.Update();
    }
```

Comment: I've followed this through, and can't get it to work for one reason or another. DbMigrator constructor, for instance, only has 1 parameter. Honestly wondering why MS added this logging endpoint if it is so inaccessible.

Comment: @dylanT I'll see if I can find some time next weekend to come up with a working example and will update the answer then.

Comment: @dylanT can you try updating your EF6 references and check again?

Comment: Thank you for posting this!
Worked really well for me, Entity Framework 6.4.4